# Facebook - Getting a python function to repeat?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am hoping someone may be able to point out the error I am making; it is probably very straight forward! 
What I am trying to do is run some code previous what I have shown below, then when I get to this point I need to get it to hold for the 600 seconds and then reload the download page:

```
try:
    # Clicks OK in Download Requested window
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    ClickOkay = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._42ft._42fu.layerCancel.uiOverlayButton.selected._42g-._42gy")
    ClickOkay.click()
except:
    print("error 2")
   # Wait Time
   # time.sleep(600)  # Allow Facebook to compile the archive

    # Reload Settings page
    GoToURL('https://www.facebook.com/' + 'settings', driver)

    # Goes back through to Download page
    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Download a copy')
    link.click()
```

At this point if the archive has finished being created then the button changes from Start Archive to Download Archive. However depending on the size of the profile the time taken to compile the archive varies. so what i was attempting (with the code below and a couple of attempts with the if and while arguments) was to get it to check if the button exists and if not go back and wait 300 seconds before trying again. Once the button appears it will then continue on to download using additional code.

```
    try:
        print("Checking if button exists")
        DownloadArchive = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("._42ft._42fu.selected._42gz._42gy")
        print(DownloadArchive.count())

        if(DownloadArchive.count() > 0):
            print("button exists")
        else:
            print("button does not exist")
        # Button to initiate password entry popup window
        #driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        #while (DownloadArchive = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._42ft._42fu.selected._42gz._42gy")):
        #    if (DownloadArchive = True):
        #        DownloadArchive.click()
        #        print("wait")
        #    else:time.sleep(300)
```

Thanks in advance, James

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing the assignment operator (`=`) with the equal operator (`==`).

So it should be:

```
while (DownloadArchive == driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._42ft._42fu.selected._42gz._42gy")):
    if (DownloadArchive == True):
```

Or just:

```
while DownloadArchive == driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._42ft._42fu.selected._42gz._42gy"):
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The `if` is redundant, either way.